# CSS how to automatically resize my div to fit the content?

Tags: html, css

Please see my http://jsfiddle.net/ob5rmnk2/7/ and as you can see my paragraph texts are displaying outside of my `div` content.

How can change the `CSS` so that the texts can automatically resize to fit into my content's `div`? I need the content div to automatically resize I believe.

If you make the screen smaller you can see the text starts to collapse and it display beyond the content's block height which I want to fix. I want it to always be display inside the content div.

Also, how can I make my `buttons` so that they can automatically have a 50px gaps (or some fixed space) from the paragraphs above it all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Changes I did:

1. `word-wrap: break-word;` in `test-inner-right` css class so that we break on the actual text (since we do not really have spaces)
2. Removed `height: 100px;` in both `test-inner-right and`test-inner-left` css classes. Since having fixed height would not make it "auto resize"

Snippet:

```css
.test-prompt {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.test-prompt-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .8;
}

.test-prompt-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.test-prompt-content-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #3F3F3F;
  text-align: center;
}

.test-prompt-content-buttons {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px, auto;
}

.test-inner-right {
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  /*width: 300px;*/
  max-width: 80%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: left;
}

.test-inner-left {
  float: left;
  /*width: 10px;*/
  max-width: 10%;
  color: blue;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.test-inner {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-prompt">
  <div class="test-prompt-backdrop"></div>
  <div class="test-prompt-content">
    <div class="test-prompt-content-title">
      <p class="test-1"></p>
      <br /> Title
    </div>

    <div class="test-inner">

      <div class="test-inner-left">
        <p class="test">

        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="test-inner-right">
        <p>
          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        </p>
        <p>
          bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="test-prompt-content-buttons">
        <div>
          <button id="continue" type="button">Continue</button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <button id="cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation is not a very good answer. What was wrong? What did you change? Why _that/those_ change(s)? There's so much that I can't even _find_ what's different between the OP's fiddle and your code. A code dump does not answer the question _"how to automatically resize my div to fit the content?"_

Comment: @StephenP that is fair my friend. Added the changes.

Answer (score 0):

your word is not wrapping because it is just one word without spaces, if you want to fit that inside use `word-wrap: break-word;`
alternatively you can use  `word-break: break-all;` depends on how you want to break them

Comment: ahhhhhh...you are right. Thx. How can I make the content box resize to fit the text?

Comment: @Activex remove `width:350px;` and control the width of the div using `max-width` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `word-break: break-all` in your CSS `.test-inner-right`, like this:

```
.test-inner-right {
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*width: 300px;*/
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: left;

    word-break: break-all;
}
```